# How to re use the Condition Filter Field in Magento Admin side?

Tags: admin, adminhtml, price-rules

How to re use condition filter field in magento with custom filters. By Condition filter I meant the control which is used to select products to which the catalog price rules are applied.

If you could point out to some docs, It would be great.

Answer (score 0):

**Good news:** The code for rules and conditions is abstracted in `Mage_Rule` so that it is reusable.

**Bad news:** There is no documentation. The best documentation you can get is the core code. Take a look at how the `Mage_CatalogRule` module uses it. And prepare to copy and adjust lots of code from templates and controllers.

Comment: Have you try to add condition rule in magento report section in filter Form. I have try and condition rule is shows up but when i try to click on plus icon or add more condition it won;t work either.

Comment: No, haven't tried that. Sounds like a Javascript issue

Comment: thanks but i compared with sales rules js and also added  setCanLoadExtJs and setCanLoadRulesJs in layout file still no luck found